# Filling SelectList with javascript cshtml

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to fill a SelectList from client side.
This is the code I have.

```
function loadSched() {
            var dsId = $(this).val();
            $('#ScheduleId option:not(:first)').remove();

            $.get('/Appointments/GetSchedulesForDoctor?docId=' + dsId)
            .success(function (gn) {
                // alert('start');
                $.each(gn, function () {
                    $('#ScheduleId').append($('<option/>', { value: this.Value }).text(this.Text));
                });
                // alert('end');
            });
        };

        function initCreate() {
            $('#DoctorId').on('change', loadSched);
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            initCreate();
        });
```

`/Appointments/GetSchedulesForDoctor?docId=` this path returns json correctly. so no issue with that. what I am trying is fill the #ScheduleId when the #DoctorId changes. 
Developer console caught that the error is `Uncaught TypeError: $.get(...).success is not a function(…)`

What I am doing wrong? same type of function works in another project.

Comment: `$.get(yourUrl, function(gn) { .... });`

Comment: Ok. now the error is gone. but SelectList not getting filled.

Comment: `$.each(gn, function (index, item) { $('#ScheduleId').append($('<option/>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text)); });` but this suggests your returning `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the controller which means your sending extra data you do not even use - just send a collection of anonymous objects containing just the 2 values you need

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) "**Deprecation Notice**: The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0"

Comment: I am using jQuery 3.1.1

Comment: Thus there is no `success` function on the `jqXHR` type returned from `$.get(url)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery 3 the following functions were removed from the `jqXHR` instance returned from `$.get(url)`:

```
jqXHR.success();
jqXHR.error()
jqXHR.complete()
```

the deprecation notice in the `jqXHR` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) says to use the following instead:

```
jqXHR.done()
jqXHR.fail()
jqXHR.always()
```

(documented on the same page).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$.each(gn, function () {
    var option = $("<option>");

    option.attr("value", this.Value).attr("text", this.Text);

    $('#ScheduleId').append(option);
});
```